# Nested MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I came across the following code while constructing a php file:

```
  $query="UPDATE EXPERTS SET ...";  
  $result=$db->query($query);         
      if ($result) 
      {     
        $query="UPDATE USERS SET ...";  
        $result=$db->query($query);     
        if ($result) 
        {       
          ...
        }
      }
```

My question is if the above nested query is acceptable since we use the same variable ($result). Of course, it works, however I am not sure if is there any case of creating unexpected results...

Thank you

Comment: One `$result` overwrites the other `$result`. If you're good with that, then OK.

Comment: Creating unexpected results....such as....?

Comment: No Worry, Your $result variable overwrite everytime

Comment: There's probably nothing of value to overwrite because an `UPDATE` query produces only `true/false` as its output. There's no result set in `$result` (unless you are using a strange custom class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Data Flow Anomalies* for this:

**Required terminology:**

- d($var) - Value assigned to $var or initialized.
- r($var) - Value of $var read.
- u($var) - Value of $var is undefined.

**We wish to avoid the following patterns:**

- ur - A undefined value is read.
- du - A variable which once had a value becomes undefined before it's read.
- dd - A variable receives a new value before it's earlier value is properly used; this is probably what you're afraid of.

**Now let's take a look:**

```
$query="UPDATE EXPERTS SET ...";            
$result=$db->query($query);                        d($result)
if ($result)                                       r($result)
{     
    $query="UPDATE USERS SET ...";  
    $result=$db->query($query);                    d($result)
    if ($result)                                   r($result)
    {       
        ...
    }
}
```

You got two *dr* so we can safely assume that you got nothing to worry about; in both cases the values are assigned and read before being assigned again.

One might argue that you *should* make a single variable which's purpose is to indicate the result of a single query but that's up to you.